# php return json with angularjs error

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I am new with php and angularjs ,

I have php code , it can return json data like this

```
{id:10, sessionName:99, computer:99, quality:LAN(very fast), networkAuthentication:Disable,…}
{id:13, sessionName:55, computer:55, quality:LAN(very fast), networkAuthentication:Disable,…}
{id:14, sessionName:bb, computer:bb, quality:LAN(very fast), networkAuthentication:Disable,…}   
{id:15, sessionName:77, computer:77, quality:LAN(very fast), networkAuthentication:Disable,…}
{id:16, sessionName:00, computer:00, quality:LAN(very fast), networkAuthentication:Disable,…}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
  include 'config_open_db.php';

  $sql= "select * from rdp";
  $sth = mysql_query($sql);
  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }
  print json_encode($rows);

 ?>
```

I want get data with angular scope

Angularjs CODE

```
angular.module('remoteApp')
 .factory('Rdpservice2', function ($resource) {
return $resource('scripts/services/rdp2.php', {}, {
  query:  {method: 'GET'}
  });
});


$scope.rdpDate = {'test': Rdpservice2.query()};
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'
```

but $scope.rdpData can't get any data?

I am so confused, please help

Comment: If you have no copy errors in your JSON, the it is indeed invalid. It should be `[{...},{...},...]`. I.e. brackets around the objects and commas between them.

Comment: $scope.rdpDate = {'test': [Rdpservice2.query()]}; it still get nothing ?

Comment: The JSON output you've pasted is not from `json_encode( $rows );`; where does it come from?

Comment: sorry , I can't understand it, would you say more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rdpservice2.query()` expects an array.

Try adding `isArray = True` to `{method: 'GET'}` 
That is, `{method: 'GET', isArray: true}`